# jqGrid giving exception when json is attempted to be loaded

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I have the following html in my site:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/Styles/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script><link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="Styles/Site.css" />

...

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#tblScheduledReleases").jqGrid({
            url: '/Release/GetScheduledReleases',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Version', 'Name', 'Scheduled Date'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', width: 55 },
                { name: 'version', width: 90 },
                { name: 'name', width: 100 },
                { name: 'date', width: 90 }
                  ],
            autowidth: true,
            sortname: 'date',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Scheduled Releases"
        });
    });
</script>

....

<table id="tblScheduledReleases"></table>
<div id="divScheduledPager"></div>
```

Now when this loads the grid shows with the correct columns and then shows the `Loading` message.  However, it is perpetually stuck in the loading section.  Opening up the chrome console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined in jquery.jqGrid.min.js:14
```

Here is the Json being returned by my webserver requested by the jqGrid:

```
{
  "page":"1",
  "total":"1",
  "records":6,
  "rows":[
    {"id":"37","version":"4.14.9.1","name":"4.14 Patch 8","date":"2010-07-08"},
    {"id":"39","version":"4.15.4.1","name":"4.15 Patch 3","date":"2010-07-08"},
    {"id":"36","version":"4.13.11.1","name":"4.13 Patch 11","date":"2010-07-15"},
    {"id":"40","version":"4.15.5.1","name":"4.15 Patch 4","date":"2010-07-22"},
    {"id":"38","version":"4.14.10.1","name":"4.14 Patch 9","date":"2010-07-22"},
    {"id":"30","version":"4.16.1.1","name":"4.16 Release","date":"2010-07-30"}
  ]
}
```

Why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should include

```
 jsonReader : { repeatitems: false }
```

in the jqGrid parameters.

Comment: It must work! Default value of `repeatitems` is `true` and jqGrid try to read all by numbers, so instead of every element in row like {"id":"37","version":"4.14.9.1","name":"4.14 Patch 8","date":"2010-07-08"} for example you should have array ["37","4.14.9.1","4.14 Patch 8","2010-07-08"].

Comment: @Steven: You are welcome! The answer is very old. If you use more resent version of jqGrid (for example [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.0, which I develop) then jqGrid *automatically* switch from default `repeatitems: true` to `repeatitems: false`.

Comment: @Oleg! Thanks for the wonderfull development of jqGrid. I'm currently working on a maintenace job of a site that uses 4.3 on many pages, so i'll stick with that one for now. I will consider the latest version on any new dev.

Comment: @Steven: You are welcome! I tried to hold the compatibility with previous versions of jqGrid and just fixed many old bugs, improved performance and added new features *without breaking the compatibility*. Of cause 100% compatibility is not possible in reality, but it works very good. The simplest way to try it - just by changing (at least temporary) URLs to jqGrid files to the URLs on CDN described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs). If all works OK, then you can add Font Awesome and improve the look of the site.

Comment: @Steven: See [the article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8) about adding of Font Awesome. If you can add `font-awesome.min.css` on all pages then you can set `iconSet: "fontAwesome"` option globally too and your old site will looks more modern.