# JQGrid Not populating data. (Always empty grid)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, get, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a jqGrid with MVC4 WebApi. I have looked through various example and finally using this [link](http://techbrij.com/add-edit-delete-jqgrid-asp-net-web-api) as reference.
The issue is grid is not populating with data but it is hitting server's GET method(Kept breakpoint there to test). I have hosted my app on local IIS. Below is jqgrid page(index.htm)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>My First Grid</title>
    <link href="../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        html, body {
            font-size: 75%;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var API_URL = "/WebApiOne/api/task/";
            jQuery("#gridMain").jqGrid({
                url: API_URL,
                data : API_URL,
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                mtype: 'GET',
                pager: '#pagernav',
                sortable: true,
                height: 200,
                viewrecords: true,
                colNames: ['TaskID', 'ProjectID', 'ProjectName', 'TaskName', 'TaskStatus'],
                colModel: [{ name: 'TaskID', index: 'TaskID', width: 40, sorttype: "int" },
                 { name: 'ProjectID', index: 'ProjectID', editable: true, edittype: 'int', width: 70 },
                 { name: 'ProjectName', index: 'ProjectName', editable: true, edittype: 'text', width: 70 },
                 { name: 'TaskName', index: 'TaskName', editable: true, edittype: 'text', width: 50, align: "right" },
                 { name: 'TaskStatus', index: 'TaskStatus', editable: true, edittype: 'text', width: 50, align: "right"}
                ],
                caption: "CRUD With ASP.NET Web API",
                autowidth: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="gridMain">
    </table>
    <div id="pagernav">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Server Side Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApiOne.Controllers
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/task
        public IEnumerable<Task> Get()
        {
            Task[] tasks = new Task[2];

            tasks[0] = new Task()
            {
                TaskID = 1,
                ProjectID = 1,
                ProjectName = "ProjectOne",
                TaskName = "FirstPage Development",
                TaskStatus = "InProgress"

            };

            tasks[1] = new Task()
            {
                TaskID = 2,
                ProjectID = 1,
                ProjectName = "ProjectOne",
                TaskName = "Second Page Development",
                TaskStatus = "Yet To Start"

            };

            return tasks;
        }

        // GET api/task/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/task
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/task/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/task/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But When I browse for localhost/WebApiOne/api/task/ I get raw data in json format as  :`[{"TaskID":1,"ProjectID":1,"ProjectName":"ProjectOne","TaskName":"FirstPage Development","TaskStatus":"InProgress"},{"TaskID":2,"ProjectID":1,"ProjectName":"ProjectOne","TaskName":"Second Page Development","TaskStatus":"Yet To Start"}]`

It proves that Server is functional and I am missing something on front end.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? Is `TaskID` value is different in all items returned by `WebApiOne/api/task/` (can `TaskID` be used as rowid)?

Comment: version - @license jqGrid  4.4.4  - jQuery Grid

Comment: Yes.. TaskID is different in all items returned by `WebApiOne/api/task/`

Comment: @Oleg : I have installed jqgrig in my VS2012 using package manager console with this command **Install-Package jQuery.jqGrid**

Comment: Good tutorial for JQGRID - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822405/Using-jqGrid-in-an-MVC-Web-Application

Comment: I agree, that the article can be helpful for understanding how jqGrid works. I read it shortly after publishing and have found a lot of small errors and things which I found not good. So I wrote my comment http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/822405/Using-jqGrid-in-an-MVC-Web-Application?msg=4914798#xx4914798xx

Comment: @Oleg : I will go through your recommendations mentioned there. and you got my project? I sent the google drive link over stackoverflow chat

Comment: I found it now. I have to do some things for my customer now, but I will send you the modified demo later.

Comment: I posted modified demo under http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/WebApiOne.zip You should set breakpoints inside of server code and use Fiddler to see that all requests works as expected. I used URLs from CDN (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)), but for intranet solution you can use local files instead. The server code should implement delete/edit/add in database of cause. After editing the data will be reloaded from server to be sure that one use the last data and server side id after Add be assigned.

Comment: I used `reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }` to force reloading from **server** after editing. You can of cause add custom editing options inside of `formEditing` or `formDeleting`. For example you can place `closeAfterAdd: true, closeAfterEdit: true` inside of `formEditing`. The new style of editing options are described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/New-style-of-usage-options-of-internal-methods). I added the usage of Font Awesome too (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you **don't use old versions of jqGrid** like version 4.4.4 published more as 2.5 years ago. I would recommend you to use the current version (4.9.2) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). If you use prefer to use NuGet, then you can use `Install-Package free-jqGrid` to install the current version of free jqGrid (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/)). See [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and readme to every published version for additional information.

Some changes can be used independent from the version of jqGrid:

- `data : API_URL` should be removed if you use `datatype: 'json'`.
- `contentType` is the option of `jQuery.ajax`. If you need to set it in jqGrid you should use `ajaxGridOptions: {contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}`.
- if you use old version of jqGrid then you need add `jsonReader` in the form `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, root: function (obj) { return obj; }}`. If you use free jqGrid then it will detect the structure of your currect JSON response automatically and no `jsonReader` is required.
- You should add `loadonce: true` option if you plan don't implement server side paging and sorting of data. You should return **all the data** and once and jqGrid will do sorting, paging and filtering on the client side.
- if you use old version of jqGrid you should add `gridview: true` to improve the performance. Free jqGrid use the option as default.
- I would recommend you to use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 200`, but the best choice depends on your exact requirements.
- You should add `autoencode: true` option if the data returned from the server are pure data and not HTML fragments for the cells.
- I recommend you remove unneeded `index` properties from `colModel` and the values with default values (`edittype: 'text'`).
- You should add `key: true` property to `TaskID` column. Input data **have to** contains information about rowid. Especially to be able to edit the data you should use correct rowid values.
- if you use free jqGrid then you can remove `<div id="pagernav"></div>` and replace `pager: '#pagernav'` with `pager: true` option. Free jqGrid can automatically create the required `<div>` for the pager.

**UPDATED:** The server code could be modified to the following for example:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApiOne.Controllers
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string TaskStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/task
        public IEnumerable<Task> Get() {
            Task[] tasks = {
                new Task {
                    TaskID = 1,
                    ProjectID = 1,
                    ProjectName = "ProjectOne",
                    TaskName = "FirstPage Development",
                    TaskStatus = "InProgress"
                },
                new Task {
                    TaskID = 2,
                    ProjectID = 1,
                    ProjectName = "ProjectOne",
                    TaskName = "Second Page Development",
                    TaskStatus = "Yet To Start"

                }
            };
            return tasks;
        }

        // GET api/task/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/task
        public void Post ([FromBody]Task task)
        {
            //perform new Row Add to DB
            // task.TaskID will be 0 here
        }

        // PUT api/task/5
        public void Put (int id, [FromBody]Task task)
        {
            //perform Db Update
            // task.TaskID and id are identical
        }

        // DELETE api/task/5
        public void Delete (int id)
        {
            // Delete row in DB.
        }
    }
}
```

The client code can be

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var apiUrl = "/WebApiOne/api/task/";
    jQuery("#gridMain").jqGrid({
        url: apiUrl,
        editurl: apiUrl,
        datatype: "json",
        gridview: true,
        height: "auto",
        iconSet: "fontAwesome",
        autoencode: true,
        sortable: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        prmNames: { id: "TaskID" },
        colNames: ["TaskID", "ProjectID", "ProjectName", "TaskName", "TaskStatus"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "TaskID", width: 60, key: true, editable: false, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: "ProjectID", width: 90 },
            { name: "ProjectName", width: 190 },
            { name: "TaskName", width: 170, align: "right" },
            { name: "TaskStatus", width: 170, align: "right" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { editable: true },
        //autowidth: true,
        formEditing: {
            width: 400,
            reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
            serializeEditData: function (postdata) {
                var copyOfPostdata = $.extend({}, postdata);
                if (postdata.TaskID === "_empty") { // ADD operation
                    postdata.TaskID = 0; // to be easy to deserialize
                }
                delete copyOfPostdata.oper; // remove unneeded oper parameter
                return copyOfPostdata;
            }
        },
        formDeleting: {
            mtype: "DELETE",
            reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true },
            serializeDelData: function () {
                return ""; // don't send and body for the HTTP DELETE
            },
            onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
                //var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to internal parameters
                //p.datatype = "json";
                options.url = apiUrl + encodeURIComponent(postdata[0]);
            }
        },
        pager: true
    }).jqGrid("navGrid", {}, {
        mtype: "PUT",
        onclickSubmit: function (options, postdata) {
            //var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"); // get reference to internal parameters
            //p.datatype = "json"; // reset datatype to reload from the server
            options.url = apiUrl + encodeURIComponent(postdata[this.id + "_id"]);
        }
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar") // add searching toolbar for local sorting (bacsue of loadonce:true) in the grid
        .jqGrid("gridResize");
});
```

The above code uses [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) with [Font Awesome](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Using-Font-Awesome-in-free-jqGrid-4.8). The corresponding demo project you can load from [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/WebApiOne.zip). You should set breakpoints inside of server code and use Fiddler to see that all requests works as expected. The server code should implement delete/edit/add in database of cause. It's important to understand that the demo are based on your original code and it don't modify any data in the database. After editing the data will be reloaded from server to be sure that one use the last data and server side id after Add be assigned. Because the data will be not saved in the database or modified on the server the data will be display unchanged in the grid after loading. It means just that the server code need be extended to support modifications of data. I wanted just show how to configure *client part* (jqGrid) to send correct requests to the server.

Comment: I am trying all the changes you have recommended, Will update you in some time and Thank you for awesome answer(completely elaborated)

Comment: I have changed `repeatitems` to false in `jsonReader: {repeatitems: true, root: function (obj) { return obj; }}` as per the answer posted by you at link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213984/jqgrid-giving-exception-when-json-is-attempted-to-be-loaded

Comment: It worked!!! THANKS ALOT :D. Stack is preventing me to up vote it more than 1 time. Otherwise I would have upvoted it to 100. A grand SALUTE to you :)

Comment: @SandeepKushwah: Sorry, `repeatitems: true`  was of cause typing error. it should be `repeatitems: false`. If you use new versions of jqGrid then the value is not really important and it will by fixed by jqGrid automatically. I fixed `repeatitems` used in my answer.

Comment: Now I am trying your `free-jqGrid` library. Apart from this Could you please give me a good reference to implement ADD/EDIT/DELETE functionality using MVC4 Web Api.

Comment: @SandeepKushwah: For editing in your case you can add `prnNames: {id: "TaskID"}` option first of all. Then you should decide which editing mode (form editing, inline editing or cell editing) and in which form (for example inline editing of click, on double-click or usage `inlineNav` to add editing toolbar or usage of column with `formatter: "actions"` or `template: "actions"` in free jqGrid) you need. I recommend you to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome to make HTTP trace. You will **see** the data which will be send on Add/Edit/Delete .

Comment: Okay. I am trying that now, If I face any issues that cannot be fixed by googling, I will post new question and give you the link..

Comment: @SandeepKushwah: There are some old posts which can be helpful for you, but the exact implementation of server part could a little depend on the editing mode which you choose. I don't find the good example with WebAPI now, but [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7365228/315935) and HTTP trace should help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89955/discussion-between-sandeep-kushwah-and-oleg).

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your jqGrid definition

```html
jsonReader : {
   repeatitems: false
},
```

Comment: It should work. Try below code in your action. First change the return type for your action to JsonResult and add below code. `return Json(tasks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: `return Json(tasks, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` is having some syntax errors